# What is the difference between HTTP 408 and 504 errors?

Tags: http, timeout, http-status-code-504, http-status-code-408

These are both timeout errors, but who is timing out in a 408 vs. a 504?

From [w3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), 408 is defined as:

> The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time.

...And 504 is:

> The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from the upstream server specified by the URI (e.g. HTTP, FTP, LDAP) or some other auxiliary server (e.g. DNS) it needed to access in attempting to complete the request.

So who is the 'client' in the 408 if not an intermediary server? If it's an actual end user, how does a server know to wait for their request before they have made it?

Comment: You're looking at a very outdated spec; it has been replaced by RFCs 7230...5.

Comment: @JulianReschke I can't find any mention of 408 or 504 in here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230 is this what you are referring to?

Comment: The status codes are defined in RFC 7231 (the spec has been split into multiple RFCs).

Comment: @JulianReschke great, thanks. Those new definitions do seem extremely similar to me, if you've got any thoughts on the differences between them and the old definitions I'd be interested to hear it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client is the browser or client application. The server knows to wait for a request because it has accepted a connection, or already read part of the request, say a header or two.

Comment: What http status would I receive if the server received a request but the response timed out?

Comment: @Sameer You wouldn’t. The status code is part of the response. If the response times out you wouldn't receive it. Your question doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 3):

**Amazon** documentation tells: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http408

> Indicates that the client cancelled the request or failed to send a full request

**Mozilla** documentation tells: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/408

> The HTTP 408 Request Timeout response status code means that the server would like to shut down this unused connection. It is sent on an idle connection by some servers, even without any previous request by the client